# Amazon EC2: How to delay shutdown after getting a termination command?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I'm looking for any ideas how can I delay termination of an EC2 instance. My bash script runs via `chkconfig` when the OS begins to shutdown. Formerly, my logs had a small size and the script copied them to S3. But now the logs are big and the OS shutdowns faster than my script finishes its work.

- I know about lifecycle-hook AWS option - it doesn't help me in my case.
- Also I don't have an idea how to frequently rotate the logs and move them to S3.

But it would be nice to configure the OS to hold the shutdown process after getting the AWS command to shutdown.

Thank you all for useful answers!

Comment: Don't dump the logs at shut down, stream them elsewhere during BUA.  Maybe use AWS Cloudwatch Logs?

Comment: Another alternative... Use the `aws s3 sync` command from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to sync the logs files with S3 on a regular basis (eg every 5 minutes). That way, the shutdown script would only have to sync data added/changed in the previous 5 minutes.

Comment: As variant. But when instance is crashed I'm interesting in latest logs to know a reasons of crashing ;)

Comment: Vorsprung I liked your proposition to use AWS Cloudwatch Logs Agent. It can stream logs each 5 seconds. It is something like ELK but much better for aws! Thank you for good idea - I hope it will help me :)